# How to select in between?

Tags: mysql, select, points, rank

I have a table, called Level.

```
id  |  level  |  points(minimum)  
-------------------------
1   |  1      |  0 
2   |  2      |  100 
3   |  3      |  200
```

Let say I have 189 points, how do i check which level the user in?

EDIT:

Best answer chosen. Now I am comparing the request by adding EXPLAIN before the SELECT query, i have this result:

```
id  |  select_type  |  table  |  type  |  possible_keys  |  key  |  key_len  |  ref  |  rows  |  Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |    SIMPLE     |  level  |   ALL  |       NULL      |  NULL |    NULL   |  NULL |  8   |  Using where


id  |  select_type  |  table  |  type  |  possible_keys  |  key  |  key_len  |  ref  |  rows  |  Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |    SIMPLE     |  level  |   ALL  |       NULL      |  NULL |    NULL   |  NULL |  8   |  Using where; Using filesort
```

How do i know which one is better or faster?

Comment: The column could be named better, like `points_limit`, or `points_cap`

Comment: @mysqllearner: Use the explain plan to find out what is faster - you do this by putting `explain` at the start of the SELECT, before the SELECT: `EXPLAIN SELECT MAX(level) FROM LEVEL WHERE points <= 189`.  Post the plans if you want help determining.

Comment: Sure, I am testing now. Will post the result very soon :)

Comment: In my explain tests, without indexes & `level` is an integer data type, they are identical except for the Extra column.  The `LIMIT` query has "using where; using filesort" - the MAX version just has "using where".  The max doesn't have "using filesore", it's more efficient.  Read this for what "using filesort" means: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for the level that the player is currently in, you want to select the maximum level with a points requirement less than the points the player currently has:

```
select max(level) from level where points <= 189;
```

This may work better if each level has a `min_points` and `max_points` amount:

```
id | level | min_points | max_points
------------------------------------
1  |   1   | 0          | 99
2  |   2   | 100        | 199
3  |   3   | 200        | 299
```

Then your query wouldn't need to aggregate:

```
select * from level where min_points <= 189 && max_points > 189;
```

Edit: ugh, I keep messing up my SQL tonight, LOL.

Comment: I was thinking about the max/min columns too, but the setup the OP lists is best.  There's no concern with one range overlapping another, and the max/min is an exponential increase in columns based on the number of levels.

Comment: Sorry, not exponential, but multiplication

Comment: @matt: Seems like your, matt and Madcoder answer are working fine. Now I am wondering, which method/query is better/faster?? Please advice. Even if it faster in few milliseconds

Comment: weird, i use this: select max(level) from level where points <= 189;
I try 245 or 189, the result is: level 1. Why??

Comment: I think i know why. The level column is varchar type, not int, so i cant use max() right?

Comment: Not sure... I created the table and am getting level 3 for 245 and level 2 for 189.

Comment: Oh... then you'd need to select max(id) instead.

Comment: I tested too - works fine, assuming level is an integer.  I thought it might've had something to do with level appearing to be a MySQL keyword, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't require a 'between' or any kind of aggregate function at all.. you could just select all rows that are less than the points, sort descending, and then first row should be the correct one.

`select level from Level where points <= 189 order by points desc limit 1`

(Assuming MySQL .. if you do not have MySQL, 'limit' may not work)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT `level` FROM `Level` WHERE `points`=189
```

Comment: yeah, you got me wrong. i didnt mean like this, but thanks anyway for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(level) from level where points <= 189
```

This assumes the 'points' field in the table is the mininum points ot achieve that level.